# Routing in one component, links in another

Tags: reactjs, router

This may sound like a stupid question but I couldn't find any answer. I have a navigation bar on App.js, on my react project where I switch between components:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users">
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users/user1">
        <User1 />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

And on my users page I want to put up a Link that takes me to /users/user-1 basically. So when I click that link instead of the Users component that I'm currently on, to render the User1 component. I tried like this:

```
<Link to='/users/user1'>User 1</Link>
```

But it doesn't render anything, it changes the url but the component remains Users.

Also as a sidenote, my users component is called in my App.js alongside the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you are using `react-router-dom`)

This is because the URL `users/user-1` matches the first `<Route />` path. It matches `/users`. If you want `/users` to only render on `/users` and not on `/users/something` then you have to add the `exact` prop.

```js
<Route exact path="/users">
  <Users />
</Route>
```

See the documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Example with multiple possible route matches:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about">
    <About />
  </Route>
  <Route exact path="/users">
    <Users />
  </Route>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users/user1">
    <User1 />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom, i added exact to the users path but still it won't render user1 component. Does it have anything to do with the fact that on the switch i have the following:      <Route path='/users/user1'> <User1 /> </Route> in the App.js and not in the component where i have the Link which reffers to the user1 url?

Comment: @SergiuTonț Try adding `exact` to the other routes that the current URL could match such as `/`. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: It did work, the problem was i forgot an exact to the / path. Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: Glad it helped @SergiuTonț. Kindly upvote & mark my answer as the solution :)